# Azure Functions call a binary executable, stream standard output to response (e.g. child_process.spawn for node.js)

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger. I'd like to call a binary file via node.js and/or C# and stream its standard output to the response, also setting the HTTP status code in the process.

I haven't been able to do so via the usual techniques used by wrappers for AWS Lambda  (e.g. child_process.spawn for node.js) though I may have missed something simple. It is trivial to do via batch functions, with the exception of setting the status code and I haven't checked whether the response truly streams. Are there any examples out there for doing this via node.js and/or C#?

Answer (score 1):

Aaron,

This should work as it does outside of the Azure Functions environment.

There are a lot of examples of how execute a process and read its output in C#/Node, so I won't spend a lot of time on that, but here is a quick function sample that runs `dir` and prints the directories:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Executing");
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\dir.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"D:\home";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        log.Info(output);
    }
}
```

About streaming the output, although possible, it isn't recommended from Azure Functions (at least not at the moment).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Fabio, I'd tried doing something like this asynchronously with .NET (I may attach snippet later). In this example it looks like output would contain the entire result from the execution. While I don't know if Azure Functions will "stream" the result, I had tried doing something like child_process.spawn example shown at this link via node.js: https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2014/08/19/Avoid-Command-Injection-Node.js - it just didn't get sent over the wire.

Comment: Updated with a comment about streaming.